# Quick Simple Product Creation stuck on Please wait... screen

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, simple-product

When I have a configurable product, I can't associate products through the Quick simple product creation menu because the screen gets stuck on the loading Please wait... screen.. It doesn't matter how long I wait, the simple product will not be created.
I thought at first it was maybe a javascript thing, so I removed all the js from the server and uploaded the js from a fresh install (1.7.0.2 version) but still the problem persists.
When I create a simple product normally I can assign it fine, but it would be quicker and less error-prone if we could add simple products through the quick simple product creation menu.

[image]
Anyone have any idea what might be wrong?